# Pre loader for index action MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013

Im trying to do a preloader for a page 
the index action controller:

myapp/FR/Index

```
public ActionResult Index(){
return View(db.SP_GetRegistrosFRByID(0).ToList());}
```

the view, there isnt a begin form because is a get request:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                ...etc...<tr>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CodIden)
                    </td>


                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombres)
                    </td> ...etc
```

Comment: What isn't working?  What do you mean by "a preloader"?  It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: yes a preloader for the get request

Comment: Saying "a preloader" doesn't really answer the question of "what is a preloader"?  Please explain what you're actually trying to do and how it's not working.

Comment: i have a view that is rendered by the controller ...inside the view i have a table what i want is to have a loading modal before it gets populated

Comment: That's very broad and open-ended for a Stack Overflow question.  You could render the table with a "loading..." div and then populate the actual table rows via AJAX, for example.  (Plugins like DataTables make that pretty easy.)  Or perhaps you can load a page with the structural content and a "loading..." div while making an AJAX call to a partial view to get the table.  There are lots of approaches you can take, any number of which are going to involve some AJAX in order to render the page before fetching the rest of the data.

Answer (score 0):

As David says it's a broad and open-ended question and you can apply lot of approaches. You have not given details about how `index` gets called (form submit, button click ..)

First you need a `div` with the loader image in the view where you need the preloader to display.

```
<div id="loader" class="loader">
         Working.. &nbsp;<img src="~/Images/loading_small.gif" />
</div>
```

and now the JS function that shows/hides the `div`  with the loader image based on your data loading status.

```
function pageLoading(status) {
   if (status == 'true') {
       $("#loader").css('display', 'block');
   }
   else {
       $("#loader").css('display', 'none');
   }
}
```

Before making the AJAX request you can call `pageLoading("true");` to start displaying the image and finally when the table data gets populated call `pageLoading("false");` to hide the loading image. Something like

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'your index method url',
      success: function (partial) {
        $('#results').html(partial);
        pageLoading("false");
      }
      error: function () {
        pageLoading("false");
      }
});
```